# Python recursively jumping through a list by a given index jump or less while avoiding zeros

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to write a function that has only one argument, a list of positive integers.

It has to be recursive and find whether you can get from the start to the end while avoiding landing on 0s. It has to start at first value `list[0]` but you can jump by either the full amount or less.

For example

```
list1 = [3,1,2,0,4,0,1]
list2 = [3,2,1,0,2,0,2]
```

List 1 should return `True` as you can jump from 3 to 2 to 4 to 1.

List 2 should return `False` as it does not matter how you jump, you will land at the first 0.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
def check_level(level):
    jump = level[0]
    if level[-1] == 0:
        return False
    elif jump == 0:
        return False
    
    elif jump == 0:
        return False
    
    elif len(level) > 1:
        if level[jump] > len(level):
            return True

        elif level[-1] == 0:
            return False
        
        elif level[0] != 0:
            if level[jump] == 0:
                level[0] -= 1
                return check_level(level)
            else:
                jump_index = level.index(level[jump])
                new_level = level[jump_index:]
                return check_level(new_level)

    else:
        return True
```

It does not work with all examples and with others it comes up with an error:

````
if level[jump] > len(level):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'```

I am out of ideas on how to approach this and whether my approach is failed from the start... I hate recursion, hence I need to practice it.
````

Comment: You need to more clearly define what you mean by jump

Comment: in code or the question? It is how many spaces across the list index I want to move.

Comment: 3 at position 0 in the first list moves three spaces to the right, which hits position 3, yielding 0. Your first list doesn't seem consistent with that explanation.

Comment: when landing on 0 it was supposed to try jumping by less, hence I tried changing the first value to a new value that is one less

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that makes the answer redundant

Answer (score 1):

The general logic is:

"If you can jump to a True position, the current position is also True"

Implemented like this:

```
def checklevel(lst):
    if not lst:
        # no list is True (we are done)
        return True  
    return any( checklevel(lst[i:]) for i in range(1,lst[0]+1))

list1 = [3,1,2,0,4,0,1]
list2 = [3,2,1,0,2,0,2]

assert checklevel(list1)
assert not checklevel(list2)
```

Note that this is a terrible solution for large lists, you should try a iterative dp-table in that case.

Comment: I am fairly new to python and trying to learn recursion logic. What does this algorithm do 'physically' ? Checks every position for every possible jump?

Comment: Also, what does ```if not lst``` mean logically? That the argument is not a list or that it starts/ends with 0 ?

Comment: It tests each possible jump, so if there is a 2, it will try to jump 1 and jump 2, if either works it will return true

Comment: "not lst" is True if lst is empty (logically here that you have jumped beyond the end of the list)

Comment: Does not work with [2, 0, 3, 0] and I have no idea why. Maybe I should give up, sorry for the amount of comments

Comment: It works here, returns True, which i understand to be the correct answer?

Comment: jump to the 3, then jump off

Comment: don't give up.  you can do it

Comment: ah, my bad it is because the last digit is 0 and the exercise wants for the list to return False if the last spot is a 0.
However, if I add conditionality at the start to check for this I get an error that list index is out of range at lst[0]

Comment: ok, then i misunderstood the exercise, i thought you just had to jump off on the right side.    is it actually you have to land on every element or land on the last element or what?

Comment: you have to land on last element, don't have to land on each one. Basically avoid 0s to get on the last element.

Comment: Can I implement this in your version or do I have to change its logic?

Comment: logic is slightly different, the base cases are different.  you need to false if you jump to far, and return correct value when you are on the last element

Comment: I have managed to get it working through ifs elifs :) will try altering your way now but at least I now have something that works. Thank you a ton

Answer (score 0):

After advancing by a number of positions, you simply have to recurse with the rest of the list.  Do it for distances from 1 to the value of the first element and you're done:

```
def jumpable(A):
    if not A: return True # reaching end wins
    return any(jumpable(A[i+1:]) for i in range(A[0])) # try all distances
```

ouput:

```
print(jumpable([3,1,2,0,4,0,1])) # True
print(jumpable([3,2,1,0,2,0,2])) # False
```

To avoid creating memory wasting temporary lists you can pass an index down (instead of a sublist) and use it as the starting point for the next level of recursion:

```
def jumpable(A,i=0):
    if i>=len(A) : return True # reaching end 
    return any(jumpable(A,i+j+1) for j in range(A[i])) # try all distances
```

With a default value for i=0, you function still has only one parameter when called from the outside.